# Android: how to provide Italian translation?

Tags: android

In the below link the documentation mentions creating "res/values-fr/strings.xml" for French translations and "res/values-ja/strings.xml" for Japanese translations.  However, I couldn't find a list of all the acceptable path formats for all languages.  I assume Italian would be "res/values-it/strings.xml", but it would be great if someone knew where this is documented.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html):

The language codes are two-letter lowercase ISO language codes (such as "en") as defined by [ISO 639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes). The country codes are two-letter uppercase ISO country codes (such as "US") as defined by [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1).

Answer (score 4):

> I assume Italian would be "res/values-it/strings.xml"

Yes, it is. The resource system uses the [ISO3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) two letter country codes. See [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkCountryIso%28%29).

Comment: They're actually language codes. For example values-fr is for the french language, not only the country.